# Got Error: Invalid hook call when trying to call ReactToPrint from another functional component

Tags: reactjs

I got the error when trying to call PrintInvoice from another functional component. Appreciate if you could share how to solve the problem. Thanks

The PrintInvoice.js

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';


class ComponentToPrint extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>column 1</th>
                    <th>column 2</th>
                    <th>column 3</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>data 1</td>
                        <td>data 2</td>
                        <td>data 3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        )
    }
}




function PrintInvoice() {

    const componentRef = useRef()
    const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
        content: () => componentRef.current
    })
    
        return (

            <div>
                <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} />
                <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print</button>
            </div>

        )
}


export default PrintInvoice;
```

The Test5.js

```
import PrintInvoice from './PrintInvoice'

function Test5() {

    return (

        <button onClick={ () => PrintInvoice()}></button>
    )

}

export default Test5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some of miss on building component, for example on react print when you need to use class you need to extend Pure Component...

Another thing, your error happen since you are use PrintInvoce as a function not as a component in `Test5.js`, but its totally wrong, handlePrint this is the function must be call in needed component by define useReactToPrint for example...or by render component it self direct, for example: `<PrintInvoice />`

```
export const ComponentToPrint = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>column 1</th>
          <th>column 2</th>
          <th>column 3</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const componentRef = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} />
      <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print this out!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check [work demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-thunder-x6c9l?file=/src/App.js) for your example (with some touches)

### Update 1:

The issue is here, `const p = new PrintInvoice() p.handlePrint()` , you must call component not a function in component, in another words think like a react think, If you need a button, then call `PrintInvoice` as a component: `<PrintInvoice />` and so on...

For example, you can do what you want by this:

```
const PrintInvoice = (props) => {
  const componentRef = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} />
      <button onClick={handlePrint}>{props.text}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <PrintInvoice text="Print this out!" />
    </>
  );
```

and code is updated in demo link.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anees. I have made further test and below is working based on my test ( will share later ) Now, if I need Test5 to be a functional component, what should the code look like? The reason that I need Test5 to be functional component is because I got hundreds of lines of code already written in functional component that need to invoke ReactToPrint . Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure where to post the code so that it can be viewed nicely

Comment: Let me figure out then I will post the rest of the code

Comment: `import React from 'react'; import PrintInvoice from './PrintInvoice' import MaterialTable from 'material-table' class Test5 extends React.Component { constructor() { super() this.state = { cols: [ {title:"ID",name:"name"} ] } this.state = { data: [ {ID: "1", name: "Skin"}] } } render() { return ( <div> <MaterialTable columns={this.cols} data={this.data} /> <PrintInvoice /> </div> ) } } export default Test5;`

Comment: `import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';

class ComponentToPrint extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>column 1</th>
                    <th>column 2</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>data 1</td>
                        <td>data 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        )
    }
}

Comment: `
function PrintInvoice() {

    console.log("Enter Print ....")

    const componentRef = useRef()
    const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
        content: () => componentRef.current
    })

    React.useEffect(() => { handlePrint() }, [] );

    
        return (

            <div>
                <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} />
            </div>


        )
}

export default PrintInvoice;
`

Comment: Hi Anees, I have cut and paste your above code, it work perfectly fine, but when I try to call it from another functional component code such as below ( I change your App to PrintInvoice, then it fail with invalid Hook call                                       
                   const p = new PrintInvoice()
                    p.handlePrint()

Comment: Hi David, You are welcome

You, issue is here, `const p = new PrintInvoice() p.handlePrint() `, you must call component not a function in component, in another words think like a react think, If you need a button, then call PrintInvoice as a component: `<PrintInvoice />` and so on...I will update my answer to support what you needed

Comment: Thanks again Anees. Looking forward to your reply

Comment: You are welcome, already Answer is updated and example updated, you can check it under Update 1...Good Luck

Comment: Thanks again Anees

Comment: Amazing David, You are welcome! dont forget to accept answer if its solve issue. Good Luck!

Comment: Done, I hope I did it correctly :-)

Comment: Thank you!, yes, thats correct